# Retain zoom by rectangle selection when saving the matplotlib figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a program that plots a time series data.
The plot I have after program executes is crisp and can be zoomed in onto any resolution without any problems.
However, as soon as I save the `matplotlib` figure as a `pdf` or `svg` file, I lose the capability to zoom by rectangular selection.
Is there any way to save the `matplotlib` fig so that I retain the original resolution to the fullest.
Attached are figures to help you guys understand the problem.

Notice how in the original `matplotlib` figure object as I keep zooming in the time stamps become visible
but when I save it as a pdf or scalable vector graphics file it does not show the timestamps clearly no matter how much I zoom.
I have named the figures such so as to easily understand what each depicts.

Original `matplotlib` plot which is zoomed:

[image]

**Original `matplotlib` figure object:**

[image]

**The zoomed in fig when saved as a `pdf`:**

[image]

Comment: [Please post your code, not an image of your code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I will make a sample script to simulate same problem and will post the code.